# Javascript - Redirect parent to new page from popup

Tags: javascript, parent-child, window.open

I've got a page that opens a popup file picker window using Javascript. Once the user selects a file the parent window redirects to a page that loads the document.  I've ready many posts with the same problem, but haven't found the solution.  I have the following code:

Parent

```
openChildWindow("FileMan2.aspx?UN=<%= Header1.UserNumber %>&FormMode=OPEN&RetObj=PRINTLETTER&PrintCase=" + OpenFlag, 550, 350);

function openChildWindow(URL, width, height) {
        if (window.showModalDialog) {
            window.showModalDialog(URL, window.self, "dialogWidth:" + width + "px;dialogHeight:" + height + "px;center:yes;scroll:no;resizable:no;status:no;unadorned:no;edge:raised");
        } else {
            window.open(URL, "docman", "width=" + width + ", height=" + height + ", screenX=0, screenY=0, status=no, scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,top=200,left=200,modal=yes");
        }
    }
```

Child

```
 var URL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/CaseLetter.aspx?Case=<%= CaseNumber %>&UN=<%= Header1.UserNumber %>&Letter=" + file + "&FileName=" + file + "&COID=<%=GlobalVar.LawFirm %>&FilePath=<%= AddPath %>";
        window.opener.location.href = URL;
```

URL evaluates to "http://example.com:80/CaseLetter.aspx?Case=35251&UN=1&Letter=asdf&FileName=asdf&COID=ar000001&FilePath="

The error I'm getting is "Unable to get property 'location'of undefined or null reference.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `window.opener` doesn't work with `window.showModalDialog` https://forums.asp.net/t/1123330.aspx?using+window+opener+with+showmodaldialog

Answer (score 0):

I would go the route of storing the reference to the modal in a variable, then poll to see when the modal is closed using its `closed` boolean property like so (this will not work when running the snippet below because stackoverflow blocks modals but you can verify by copying it into your chrome dev tools console).

```js
let modal = window.open("https://www.google.com?q=cats", "docman", "width=500,height=500,screenX=0, screenY=0,status=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,top=200,left=200,modal=yes")

function onClose () {
  alert("Modal was closed")
}

let intervalID = setInterval(() => {
  if(modal && modal.closed) {
    clearTimeout(intervalID)
    onClose()
  }
}, 200)
```